# BlueJ comes up with error message "Error: ';' expected" when I try and run my Java program

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program that returns the number of letters in a word past the letter 'n' in the alphabet ("Beaver" would return 2, "v" and "r" being the two letters it counted). After I compile and go to do the method call it tells me to enter 'String letter'.

If I enter "String _____" it says "Error: cannot find symbol- variable ____ (whatever word I entered)".

If I put exactly "String letter" it says "Error: ';' expected".

Here is my code below:

```
public class alphabet{
    public static int secondHalfLetters(String letter) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < letter.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.toLowerCase(letter.charAt(i)) >= 'n') {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

I feel stuck. What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: If I read this it seems you are trying to run your code from REPL or possibly a shell prompt. Why not try and create a `main` method to call your static `secondHalfLetters` method?

Comment: Well, the code looks good to me. Are you sure your file is named `alphabet.java` and it is recompiled?

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided seems correct, and the issue you're facing is likely related to how you are trying to call the secondHalfLetters method. Here's an example of how you can call the method and retrieve the count:

```
public class Alphabet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String word = "Beaver";
        int count = secondHalfLetters(word);
        System.out.println("Number of letters past 'n' in the word: " + count);
    }

    public static int secondHalfLetters(String letter) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < letter.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.toLowerCase(letter.charAt(i)) >= 'n') {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

In the above example, the main method is called, and a string variable word is initialized with the value "Beaver". The secondHalfLetters method is then called, passing the word variable as an argument. The returned count is stored in the count variable.

Finally, the result is printed using System.out.println, displaying the number of letters past 'n' in the word.

Make sure you have a main method in your code to run it as a standalone program. Additionally, ensure that your code is properly formatted and follow Java naming conventions